# Logging queries in elasticsearch on docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, docker-compose

I'm running elasticsearch 2.4.x on docker with docker-compose for a local application. I'm trying to debug a library for querying elasticsearch so I'd like to see `docker logs elasticsearch` show me each query logged. I've tried sending options [as suggested in their logging config](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/master/2.4/config/logging.yml#L1), but as I'm an elasticsearch novice, I'm not sure where to set this as all my attempts have just resulted in errors either starting or connecting to elasticsearch.

How do I run elasticsearch on docker-compose with full logging of all queries?